# Check patterns of 5 in password "12345", "abcde"

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to validate a password string in a .NET for sequential patterns (forward or reverse) with numbers or letters of 5 or more.

Examples of patterns that will not be accepted:

```
"ABCDE",
"12345",
"54321",
"edcba"
```

I cannot find a decent regex pattern that handles finding the characters in order, currently just returning any sequence of 5 letters or numbers:

```
    public bool CheckForSequence(string input)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(input.ToUpper(), @"([A-Z])(?!\1)([A-Z])(?!\1|\2)([A-Z])(?!\1|\2|\3)([A-Z])(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)([A-Z])") || 
            Regex.IsMatch(input, @"([1-9])(?!\1)([1-9])(?!\1|\2)([1-9])(?!\1|\2|\3)([1-9])(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)([1-9])");
    }
```

Comment: Do not use a regex, it cannot do that. Use a `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Contains(input.ToUpper())` and similar for digits. You probably need to create all the input string permuations before if these can be partial substrings inside your strings. Else, that simple trick will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Computing every permutation to perform a contains on a string is turning an O(n) problem into an O(n*n!) problem.  That's turning a trivially fast operation into something that's basically untenable with even realistically small passwords.

Comment: @Servy I do not care how much it takes if it gets the job done correctly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Having a program that never finishes because you wrote something that would take more than your lifetime to finish (when it could be done in microseconds) for entirely reasonable inputs is not "getting the job done correctly".  Writing something that's 2, or even 5, times slower than it needs to be is unlikely to be a dealbreaker here, writing something that scales much worse than the factorial of the input size, unnecessarily, absolutely is.

Comment: @Servy "create all the input string permuations" never takes a lifetime. It depends what code you use to implement that. I wrote it before and it takes milliseconds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just printing all of those values to the console would take a lifetime for strings that aren't *extremely* trivially small.  The algorithm for generating the permutations is irrelevant.  The *number* of permutations scales with the factorial of the input size, even completely ignoring the work needed to compute what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably way better ways to do this, but, just for fun, I've made a simple brute-force algorithm:

```cs
bool CheckForSequence(string inp) {
    bool InRange(int c) {
        const int minLower = (int)'a';
        const int maxLower = (int)'z';
        const int minUpper = (int)'A';
        const int maxUpper = (int)'Z';
        const int minNumber = (int)'0';
        const int maxNumber = (int)'9';
        return (c >= minLower && c <= maxLower) || (c >= minUpper && c <= maxUpper) || (c >= minNumber && c <= maxNumber);
    }
    if(inp.Length < 5) return false;        
    
    for(var i = 0; i < inp.Length - 4; i++)
    {
        var c = (int)inp[i];
        if(InRange(c))
        {
            var vM = c;
            int x;
            for(x = i+1; x < i + 5; x++)
            {
                if(inp[x] != vM+1 || !InRange(inp[x])) break;
                vM++;
            }
            if(x == i+5) return true;               
            for(x = i+1; x < i + 5; x++)
            {
                if(inp[x] != vM-1 || !InRange(inp[x])) break;
                vM--;
            }
            if(x == i+5) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can see it in action [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AriYOF)

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor is correct - regex is the wrong tool for this.

Here's one possible implementation:

```
public static class SequenceChecker
{
    private static char MapChar(char c) => c switch
    {
        >= '0' and <= '9' => c,
        >= 'A' and <= 'Z' => c,
        >= 'a' and <= 'z' => (char)(c - 'a' + 'A'),
        _ => default,
    };
    
    private static bool IsSequence(ReadOnlySpan<char> input)
    {
        char x = MapChar(input[0]);
        if (x == default) return false;
        
        char y = MapChar(input[1]);
        if (y == default) return false;
        
        int direction = y - x;
        if (Math.Abs(direction) != 1) return false;
        
        for (int index = 2; index < input.Length; index++)
        {
            x = y;
            y = MapChar(input[index]);
            if (y == default) return false;
            
            int nextDirection = y - x;
            if (nextDirection != direction) return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    public static bool ContainsSequence(string input, int sequenceLength = 5)
    {
        if (sequenceLength < 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(sequenceLength));
        
        if (input is null) return false;
        if (input.Length < sequenceLength) return false;
        
        for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < 1 + input.Length - sequenceLength; startIndex++)
        {
            if (IsSequence(input.AsSpan(startIndex, sequenceLength)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Wiktor has already said, regex isn't a good way to do this. You could find the difference between consecutive characters of the string, and complain if you find a sequence of four or more ones (or -1s).

```
public bool CheckForSequence(string pass)
{
    int curr_diff = 0; // The difference between the i-1th and i-2th character
    int consec_diff = 0; // The number of consecutive pairs having the same difference
    for (int i = 1; i < pass.Length; i++)
    {
        int diff = pass[i] - pass[i - 1]; // The difference between the ith and i-1th character

        if (Math.Abs(diff) == 1 && curr_diff == diff)
        {
            // If the difference is the same, increment consec_diff
            // And check if the password is invalid
            consec_diff++;
            if (consec_diff >= 4)
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // New diff. reset curr_diff and consec_diff
            curr_diff = diff;
            consec_diff = Math.Abs(diff)==1 ? 1 : 0;
            // If the difference is 1, set consec_diff to 1 else 0
        }
    }

    return consec_diff < 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the plethora of solutions posted so far:

```
public static int LongestAscendingOrDescendingRun(string s)
{
    if (s.Length <= 1)
        return 0;

    int  longest = 0;
    int  current = 0;
    bool ascending = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        bool isAscending () => s[i]-s[i-1] == +1;
        bool isDescending() => s[i]-s[i-1] == -1;

        if (current > 0)
        {
            if (ascending)
            {
                if (isAscending())
                {
                    longest = Math.Max(longest, ++current);
                }
                else // No longer ascending.
                {
                    current = 0;
                }
            }
            else // Descending.
            {
                if (isDescending())
                {
                    longest = Math.Max(longest, ++current);
                }
                else // No longer descending.
                {
                    current = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else // No current.
        {
            if (isAscending())
            {
                ascending = true;
                current = 2;
                longest = Math.Max(longest, current);
            }
            else if (isDescending())
            {
                ascending = false;
                current = 2;
                longest = Math.Max(longest, current);
            }
        }
    }
        
    return longest;
}
```